# HTML-CSS: Custom menu does not scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS. I am trying to make a menu bar which would be fixed at the bottom of my page. I am doing various javascript operations based on the user menu selection. My menu looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/78HPq/

The HTML code for my menu bar is:

```
    <div id="menubar" >
<div id="menubar2"  style="width:1200px">
    <ol >
        <li id = 'l1' class="gbt"><a id="a1" onclick="handleLink(1)"    href="javascript:void(0);"><span id = 's1' class="gbts">Link 1</span></a></li>
        <li id = 'l2' class="gbt"><a id="a2" onclick="handleLink(2)"     href="javascript:void(0);"><span id = 's2' class="gbts">Link 2</span></a></li>
        <li id = 'l3' class="gbt"><a id="a3" onclick="handleLink(3)"     href="javascript:void(0);"><span id = 's3' class="gbts">Link 3</span></a></li>
        <li id = 'l5' class="gbt"><a id="a5" onclick="handleLink(5)"     href="javascript:void(0);"><span id = 's5' class="gbts">Link 4</span></a></li>
        <li id = 'l4' class="gbt"><a id="a4" onclick="handleLink(4)"     href="javascript:void(0);"><span id = 's4' class="gbts">Link 5</span></a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem I have however, is that if the browser window is resized to smaller than my menu bar, I don't get a horizontal scroll bar. I get one if I make my menubar position relative or absolute, but I need 'fixed' to keep it attached to the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: In summary I want my menu to: 1. scroll horizontally with page 2. NOT scroll vertically with the page and stay fixed at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: scroll;` to the #menubar. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78HPq/2/)

```
#menubar{
    z-index:999;
    bottom: 30px;

    height:65px;
    width: 105%;
    background-color: #060612;
     filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;
    line-height:35px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position:absolute;
}

body {
    overflow-x: scroll;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, appreciate it. overflow:scroll however, adds a scroll bar directly to my div. I want the whole page to scroll and the browser window to have the scroll bar.

Comment: Add position:absolute; to the #menubar css, and add overflow-x: scroll to the body css.

Comment: It seems, I can't use position:absolute as I want my menu bar fixed to the bottom of the page (30px from it actually). If I use position:absolute, the menu scrolls vertically with the page, which I don't want. Thanks for the inputs though.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes :

```
#menubar {    
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

and

```
menubar2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

should be enough. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HByL8/)

Comment: Thanks. Adding overflow to the menu bar actually adds a scroll bar to the div (menu) itself. I actually want the whole page to scroll and the browser window to have the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `overflow: scroll;`, perhaps you can try to apply `overflow: auto;` to the `body` of tour page. `auto` only add scroll bar when `overflow` happen.